Make sure android tv program poster arts are visible from any tv launcher
I have to provide some images to the android tv launcher so that my programs are displayed correctly in the relative channel. The images are in the internal storage of the app and generated at runtime, for this reason i had to create my file provider:
<provider
    android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
</provider>

and file_paths.xml
<paths>
    <files-path name="addons" path="." />
</paths>

The following function in my app adds some programs to a channel:
private fun addProgramToChannel(context: Context, channelUri: Uri, card: CardItem) {
    val posterFile = File(context.filesDir, posterUrl.substringAfter("/files/"))

    val posterUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, "${context.packageName}.fileprovider", posterFile)

    context.grantUriPermission("com.google.android.tvlauncher", posterUri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)

    val programValues = ContentValues().apply {
        put(TvContractCompat.PreviewPrograms.COLUMN_TYPE, TvContractCompat.PreviewProgramColumns.TYPE_MOVIE)
        put(TvContractCompat.PreviewPrograms.COLUMN_CHANNEL_ID, ContentUris.parseId(channelUri))
        put(TvContractCompat.PreviewPrograms.COLUMN_TITLE, card.label)  // 'label' as title
        put(TvContractCompat.PreviewPrograms.COLUMN_POSTER_ART_URI, posterUri.toString())

        put(TvContractCompat.PreviewPrograms.COLUMN_INTENT_URI, "exttv://"+card.uri)
    }

    context.contentResolver.insert(TvContractCompat.PreviewPrograms.CONTENT_URI, programValues)
}

card is just a model:
public final data class CardItem(
    val uri: String,
    val label: String,
    val label2: String,
    val plot: String,
    val thumbnailUrl: String,
    val posterUrl: String,
    val fanartUrl: String,
    val isFolder: Boolean
)

The visualization of the poster art is correct as long as I have the following line in the function:
context.grantUriPermission("com.google.android.tvlauncher", posterUri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)

The problem is that I can't predict the package name of every single android tv launcher. If i don't allow the specific launcher i get:
Load failed for content://com.android.exttv.fileprovider/addons/poster_art.jpg with size [564x306]
class yn: Failed to load resource
There was 1 cause:
java.lang.SecurityException(Permission Denial: opening provider androidx.core.content.FileProvider from ProcessRecord{e289a91 3181:com.google.android.tvlauncher/u0a32} (pid=3181, uid=10032) that is not exported from UID 10051)
call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
Cause (1 of 1): class java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider androidx.core.content.FileProvider from ProcessRecord{e289a91 3181:com.google.android.tvlauncher/u0a32} (pid=3181, uid=10032) that is not exported from UID 10051

Is there any generic solution to this problem?
